# adding values of dynamically created inputs to database

Tags: jquery, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to add values of some dynamically created inputs to a mysql database using jquery and codeignitor.

The html:

```
<td>
<input type="number" name="quantity" id="quantity" value="1">
<input type="number" name="price" id="price" value="10">
<input type="number" name="item" id="item" value="100">
</td>
<td>
<input type="number" name="quantity" id="quantity" value="5">
<input type="number" name="price" id="price" value="40">
<input type="number" name="item" id="item" value="102">
</td>
<td>
<input type="number" name="quantity" id="quantity" value="2">
<input type="number" name="price" id="price" value="14">
<input type="number" name="item" id="item" value="101">
</td>
```

The JQuery

```
$("#finish_button").click(function(e) {
var quantity = [];
var price= [];
 quantity = $('#quantity').each(function() { return this.value; }).get();
 price= $('#price').each(function() { return this.value; }).get();



          $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'sales/add_payment,
            data: values+quantity,
            success: function () {
             
            }
          });   

 });
```

Controller

```
$data= $this->input->get('data');
$this->Sale->save($data);
```

Model

```
$data = array(
    'sale_time'      => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    'item_id'    => $data['item_id'],
    'price'  => $data['price'],
    'quantity'   => $data['quantity'],

);

$this->db->insert('sales_items', $data );
```

The above code is not working and completely wrong, I am completely lost when it comes to arrays and any help would highly appreciated.

In the database I want entry to be like this:

| item_id | price | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 10 | 1 |
| 102 | 40 | 5 |
| 101 | 14 | 2 |

Comment: this doesn't make sense, can you please clarify, where this html comes from (how it is created). I suppose you want to do an update, not an insert to the database, since you must have gotten this dynamically created inputs from somewhere?

Comment: the html is created based on a select so it will be dynamic and I want the values inside each td to go as a new row in the database as I have shown how I want the result in the database

Comment: `the html is created based on a select` means please show us your task by picture?

Answer (score 0):

To to this you will treat them as array by adding [] to input fields.

```
<td>
  <input type="number" name="quantity[]" id="quantity" value="1">
  <input type="number" name="price[]" id="price" value="10">
  <input type="number" name="item[]" id="item" value="100">
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="number" name="quantity[]" id="quantity" value="5">
    <input type="number" name="price[]" id="price" value="40">
    <input type="number" name="item[]" id="item" value="102">
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="number" name="quantity[]" id="quantity" value="2">
     <input type="number" name="price[]" id="price" value="14">
     <input type="number" name="item[]" id="item" value="101">
   </td>
```

For you to be able to process the form data you will loop each of the input group data.

```
   <?php
          //count the input and iterate
           $count  = count($_POST['item'];
           for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++){
                $data = array(
                               'quantity=>$_POST['quantity'][$i],
                                'price'=>$_POST['price'][$i],
                                'item'=>$_POST['item'][$i],
                              );
                   // here you have your data you can insert into data base
                   // print_r($data); //to see what you have.
                }
   ?>
```